# time complexity recursive function

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, recursive-datastructures

How can i calculate the time complexity and the t(n) equation of this recursive function?

```
Function CoeffBin(n,k)
if (n=1) or (k=0) then return(1)
else return (CoeffBin(n-1,k) + CoeffBin(n-1,k-1))
```

Comment: If this function intends to calculate the Binomial Coefficient, then it is wrong. It does not work well once `n < k`.

Comment: Perhaps a fix would be `if (k=0) or (k=n) then return(1)` -- or is it a trick question altogether?

Comment: @trincot: it computes `B(n-1, n+k-1)=B(k, n+k-1)` for `n≥1, k≥0`  and is always right.

Comment: @YvesDaoust But, for example, B(2, 5) = B(1, 5) + B(1, 4) = 2. That's clearly wrong. Although when we start with 0<=k<=n, the base looks misplaced but perhaps indeed provides the right answer, just following a different path to 1s on the border?..

Comment: Just checked -- it's wrong, really -- assuming the goal was to compute binomial coefficients. Unless I made a mistake in Python translation: https://ideone.com/hQJ6s4 . For example, B(4, 2) is 7 instead of 6.

Comment: @Gassa: you mis-read my comment (in fact probably did not really read it). The computed function is not B(n, k).

Comment: @YvesDaoust I admit I still don't understand what's going on. Taking another look on your answers, your comments, and then my program, I now see that the computed numbers are prefix sums of rows of Pascal triangle. Still, I don't see a definition of "binomial numbers" online that matches what I see computed by my program. So I still think it's an error. __Anyway,__ whatever the exact function is, the cost function follows it closely, which is the idea of both current answers, and I think that's good enough.

Comment: @Gassa: are you serious ? You can't parse `B(k, n+k-1)` ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust What is B, where can I read its definition?

Comment: @Gassa: you know it very well, B(n,k)=n!/(k!(n-k)!).

Comment: @YvesDaoust OK, then I'm sure it's wrong :) . See comment to your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `T(n, k)` be the cost function and assume a unit cost of the statement `if (n=1) or (k=0) then return(1)`.

Now neglecting the cost of addition, we have the recurrence

```
T(n, k) =
    1 if n = 1 or k = 0 (that is T(1, k) = T(n, 0) = 1)
    T(n-1, k) + T(n-1, k-1) otherwise
```

The solution is `T(n, k)=B(n-1, n-1+k)=B(k, n-1+k)` where `B` denotes  Binomial numbers
and the costs also follows Pascal's triangle !

---

For a more precise estimate, we can assume the costs `a` when `n=1`or `k=0`, and `T(n-1,k)+T(n-1,k-1)+b` otherwise. The solution is then `(a+b)B(k, n+k-1)-b`.

Comment: I don't really understand what B is. For example, T(4,2) = T(3,2) + T(3,1) = [T(2,2) + T(2,1)] + [T(2,1) + T(2,0)] = {T(1,2) + T(1,1)} + {T(1,1) + T(1,0)} + {T(1,1) + T(1,0)} + 1 = 7. By the formula in the answer, T(4,2) = B(3,5) = B(2,5) -- but I fail to see what's B then.

Comment: If B(k,n) is just the common choose(n,k), then I'm sure it's wrong: choose(5,2) = choose(5,3) = 5! / 2! / 3! = 120 / 2 / 6 = 10, which is not equal to 7.

Comment: @Gassa: you still misread the formula. Pay attention.

Comment: Alright, either please kindly tell me what my error is, or let's drop it altogether. I'm quite okay with being wrong on the internet.

Comment: @Gassa: B(k, n-1+k) != B(n, k).

Comment: Yup, but my first comment still stands: you say T(4,2)=B(4-1,4-1+2)=B(3,5), and what I get there is not B(3,5).

Answer (score 1):

Note that, at the base level (that is, when not doing recursive calls), the function always returns ones.

So, to have an answer of X, the program will ultimately need to do X-1 additions, and thus do X calls executing the case in the first line and X-1 calls executing the second line.

So, whatever the intended result of the function call is -- perhaps choose(n,k), -- *if* you prove that it works, you automatically establish that the number of calls is proportional to that result.

Comment: I second @trincot's comment about the function not working as intended right now, but still want to assume that it's not a trick question and will be fixed, and so focus this answer on the particular approach to analyzing the complexity.

Comment: No, trincot is making a wrong assumption. The function does compute binomial coefficients faithfully, but not in the way he thinks.